# Photos being uploaded incorrectly

Tags: angularjs, dropzone.js

We are using Html, AngularJs 1.6.X, [Dropzone.JS 4.3](http://www.dropzonejs.com/), [Load Image](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image) and Azure Blob Storage.

On the client-side images are:

- Rotated according to their EXIF information
- Resized with a max size of 1280 x 960
- Uploaded to Azure Blob Storage

There are occasions where images are being uploaded zoomed-in to the top left corner.

Any ideas on how to diagnose and fix the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the images that zoom in coming from a specific type of device? I've noticed sometimes iOS exif behaves differently than other devices.

Comment: It was happening on multiple device types. I was able to replicate the issue multiple times on one android device (Huawei, running Android 6.0.1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some attempts I was able to pinpoint the issue to the scaling method of Load-Image.js.

I am not sure of what is causing the issue but replacing the library by another, a custom version of [Image-Uploader](https://github.com/rossturner/HTML5-ImageUploader), fixed the issue.

Hope this helps someone else.